# Converting long (whose decimal representation represents a yyyyMMdd.. date) to a different date format

Tags: java

I have long of the form

```
20120720162145
yyyymmddhhmmss
```

I have to convert it to `2012-07-20  4:21 PM` form. Is there any way in Java to do this using `Date`?

Comment: What sort of number is this long (or what does it mean)? It's not mili/nanoseconds since 1970-01-01 (and also not sind 1900 nor 0). Because that gives me `2607-08-08 06:56 PM`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how:

```
long input = 20120720162145L;

DateFormat inputDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
DateFormat outputDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd K:mm a");

Date date = inputDF.parse(""+input);

System.out.println(outputDF.format(date));
```

**Output:**

```
2012-07-20 4:21 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

I should like to contribute the modern answer. The answer from 2012 is correct (if you accept 0:21 PM as a time, and otherwise it’s simple to change it to 12:21 PM). Today I prefer

```
    // convert your long into a LocalDateTime
    DateTimeFormatter uuuuMmDdHhMmSs = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss");
    long longDate = 20120720162145L;
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(String.valueOf(longDate), uuuuMmDdHhMmSs);

    // Format the LocalDateTime into your desired format
    DateTimeFormatter humanReadableFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(humanReadableFormatter);
    System.out.println(formattedDateTime);
```

This prints the desired

> 2012-07-20 4:21 PM

I recommend you give explicit locale for formatting. I have given English since AM and PM are hardly used in other languages than English, but you choose.

I noticed that in your question you had two spaces between the date and the time in `2012-07-20  4:21 PM`. If you want the hours space padded so they always take up two positions (nice if formatted date-times are presented under each other in a column), use `pp` pad modifier before the `h`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter humanReadableFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd pph:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

If you want to format into `20/07/2012` (as asked [in this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558248/how-to-convert-a-long-to-a-date-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format)):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String formattedDate = dateTime.format(dateFormatter);
```

### java.time

The classes `Date`, `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` used in the answer from 2012 are now long outdated and have also proven to be poorly designed. I recommend you leave them behind and instead use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.